# Maximum socket Connection with epoll

Tags: epoll

I'm using CentOS (Linux) and was wondering

the maximum connection that one server can have through epoll (Edge Trigger, OneSHot) .

I've succeeded in having 100,016 connections doing ping-pongs (nonstop) atm. How many socket connections can one server handle?

I don't think it is unlimited. If anyone who've tried it. Could you please share ?

Comment: are these UDP connections, then? I guess it depends on CPU, right? For TCP more exact figure can be put considering the number of ports 65K and the size of wait/accept queues, but with UDP?

Comment: TCPs for the connections. Accepting and doing ping-pongs with no delay (256bytes). Maybe no delay is putting CPU overloaded.

Answer (score 2):

500,000 TCP connections from a single server is the gold standard these days. The record is over a million. It does require kernel tuning. See, for example, [Linux Kernel Tuning for C500k](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1740823).